# Is it possible to compile c++ with batch script using dev console?

Tags: c++, batch-file, compilation

So what i want to do is have my bat file launch the dev console and compile my .cpp file

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
```

this code launches the dev console but after this line i can't seem to add anything else to the bat file. For example if i were to type

```
cl test.cpp
```

under the line above the console does not compile my test.cpp but if i type it manually into the dev console it does compile it. So can i somehow make a batfile that launches the dev console and compiles my program?

I'm using windows 10 and microsoft visual studio 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a batch script that is running within the console, so there is no need to use `%comspec% /k ...`, that just gets in the way.

But you do need to use `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"` so that batch script can return to your batch script.

You can then follow that command with `cl.exe test.cpp`, etc.

Any time you want a batch script to execute another script and return, then you generally need the CALL command. (The other option is CMD /C, but that is normally not what you want)

If you don't use CALL, then control is simply transferred to the new batch script, and it never returns.

Answer (score -1):

Sure. It's *possible*. But in the long run you'll probably be a lot happier by using a *proper* build system, such as [scons](http://scons.org), [cmake](https://cmake.org)/[ninja](https://ninja-build.org) or similar.